# Products of sequentially compact spaces versus $\mathfrak{t}$ and $\mathfrak{s}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\mu$ be the minimal cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exists a sequence $(X_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa)$ with each $X_\alpha$ sequentially compact space such that $\prod_{\alpha < \kappa} X_\alpha$ is not sequentially compact.

Then, it is known that $\mathfrak{t} \le \mu \le \mathfrak{s}$.
Here, $\mathfrak{t}$ is the tower number and $\mathfrak{s}$ is the splitting number.
A proof is in E.K. van Douwen's article "The Integers and Topology" in "Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology".

Now,

1. can we separate $\mu$ from $\mathfrak{t}$ or separate $\mu$ from $\mathfrak{s}$?
   Or is it provable that $\mu = \mathfrak{t}$ or $\mu = \mathfrak{s}$ in ZFC?
2. Since in the Mathias model $\mathfrak{t} = \aleph_1$ and $\mathfrak{s} = \aleph_2$, what can be said about $\mu$ in the model?

This question is the continuation of: [For some sequentially compact space $X$, is $X^{\omega_1}$ not sequentially compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985054/for-some-sequentially-compact-space-x-is-x-omega-1-not-sequentially-comp/)

Comment: [this overview](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.153.9458&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from Open Problems in Topology seems of interest. You could look for papers that reference it, e.g. There has been some progress on some of these, maybe also loook in the  Recent Progress in General Topology books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $\mu$ you are looking for is $\mathfrak h$. This is proved in

Petr Simon, “Products of sequentially compact spaces”, in: Rendiconti dell’Istituto di Matematica dell’Università di Trieste. An International Journal of Mathematics, 25 (1993), pp. 447-450.

The cardinals $\mathfrak t$, $\mathfrak h$ and $\mathfrak s$ are consistently distinct. In Mathias model $\mathfrak s = \mathfrak h$, see, e.g., the chapter by A. Blass in the Handbook of Set Theory.

Comment: Posting links and/or references is not equivalent to posting an answer.  Please include at least an outline of the proofs you reference.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. I can add that if you want to see a proof that one can have $\mathfrak{h} < \mathfrak{s}$, this is shown in Shelah's article *On Cardinal Invariants of the Continuum* in the book *Axiomatic Set Theory*, volume 31 of *Contemporary Mathematics*, published by the American Mathematical Society. In section 5, Shelah produces a forcing that gets $\aleph_1 = \mathfrak{h} < \mathfrak{s} = \mathfrak{c} = \aleph_2$.